# javascript jquery .each() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some form input elements with class *.commission_plan* and different IDs. I need to sum up this element's values. I use this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.commission_plan').each(function() {
        total = total + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#payment_total_amount_hidden').val(total);
    $('#payment_total_amount').text('Total: ' + total);
}):
```

In my input fields are the values 3.45 and 4.65. But why does *#payment_total_amount* contain 8.100000000000001? Very strange behavior.

Comment: try to do with mapping. and get method.

Comment: @steven - `.map()` returns an array, it really isn't appropriate here, since we're after a single value at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how floating point math behaves, for currency situations you often want 2 decimal places, so use [`.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) when rendering it, like this:

```
var total = 0;
    $('.commission_plan').each(function(){
        total = total + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#payment_total_amount_hidden').val(total.toFixed(2));
    $('#payment_total_amount').text('Total: '+total.toFixed(2));
}):
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of precision issues with floating point values. You could try using the toFixed(n) javascript method to limit the number of decimal places.

Edit: As clarified by Nick in the comments the toFixed(n) method will convert a float to a string so it should only be used once the calculation is complete.

Comment: This is not the place to use it, since the result is a string.

Comment: @Nick - could you clarify why you can't use it here; I have tested the result and it appears to work as expected?

Comment: You would be adding numbers to strings, the second loop would be a string which doesn't have a `.toFixed()` method, so it would blow up.  You can test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/TQ7vn/

Comment: @Nick - thanks for that, I didn't realise the toFixed method changed the type to a string. I have edited my answer appropriately.